# Python get index of empty live

Tags: python, indexing, newline, end-of-line

This is how the response looks like

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.google.com/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Fri, 11 Sep 2015 19:18:15 GMT
Expires: Sun, 11 Oct 2015 19:18:15 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=2592000
Server: gws
Content-Length: 219
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.com/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

I want to get the index of the empty line, I have tried

```
response.index("\n\n")
```

but it does not work.

any suggestions?

thank you!

EDIT:
It give me this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 15, in <module>
    test = response.index("\n\n")
ValueError: substring not found
```

This is my full code:

```
import socket

server = "www.google.com"
server = socket.gethostbyname(server)
port = 80
request = "GET / HTTP/1.1\nHost: " + server + "\n\n"

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

sock.connect((server, port))
sock.send(request.encode())

response = sock.recv(4096)
print(response)

test = response.index("\n\n")

print(test)
```

Comment: It works for me. Are you receiving a `ValueError`?

Comment: Works for me, what is the output of `type(response)`

Comment: hmm, maybe it tries to find \n\n before the whole message has been received?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** After seeing your whole code it was easy to tell that the data received is encoded and you need to decode the data.

The important part was `response = sock.recv(4096).decode("utf-8")` which turns a bytes array into a string in python.

This bit of code works for me.

```
import socket

server = "www.google.com"
server = socket.gethostbyname(server)
port = 80
request = "GET / HTTP/1.1\nHost: " + server + "\n\n"

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

sock.connect((server, port))
sock.send(request.encode())

response = sock.recv(4096).decode("utf-8")
print(response)

test = response.index("\r\n\r")

print(test)
```

Comment: your code works for me, I think the error has to do something with the socket.

Comment: I wish I could.
May I ask you how come \n\n doesn't work but \r\n\r works?
I am on Linux.

Comment: The actual data is `\r\n\r` in the bytes array. If you print it out before decoding it you will see that it is that.